# Underscore template variables - just starting out

Tags: javascript, templates, underscore.js

Underscore templates seem pretty simple, but I'm working on my first attempt and am stumped.

I'm just trying to display a person's name in the H1.

Here's my template:

```
<script id="tmpl-index-list" type="text/template">
<% _.each(data, function(item){  %>
    <li>
        <a href="#person" data-transition="slide">
            <h1><%=item.personName%></h1>
        </a>    
    </li>
<% }); %>
```

And here's my JS:

```
var tmplMarkup = $('#tmpl-index-list').html();
var compiledTmpl = _.template( tmplMarkup, {data: IndexList.listEntries} );
$('#index-list-wrapper').html(compiledTmpl);
```

IndexList.listEntires is an array of ListEntry objects, simple key / value objects.

For example, here is the 'class':

```
function ListEntry(){
    this.img_url = '';
    this.personName = '';
    this.personID = '';
};
```

When I do a console.dir on it, the data is there, but for item.personName in the template, it comes up as undefined.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out what you get in the console: `<% _.each(data, function(item){ console.log( item ) %>`

Comment: 'item' is an array, but item[0] comes up as undefined.

Comment: Please post some precise example contents of `IndexList.listEntries`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is with the data you are passing in. You are using `IndexList.listEntries`, but you have not provided any example data.

Based on your comments, that `listEntries` is an array of objects like `ListEntry`, I have put together some sample data.

```
var IndexList = {
    listEntries : [
        {
            "img_url" : "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/72b3fbc4d71d3955deca44483322da23?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG",
            "personName" : "Tim",
            "personId" : "Tim76"
        },
        {
            "img_url" : "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0927a92a180a7552e2119742ede9b9cf?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
            "personName" : "Rob",
            "personId" : "Robert Price"
        }
    ]
};
```

Using this data, your template correctly shows both "Tim" and "Rob" as list items when run.

I suggest you go and look again at the `IndexList` data you are trying to use, the problem is almost certainly there.